# .jsp page not seeing newly added function to compiled java .class file

Tags: java, jsp, methods

I'm working in another company's code base for a .jsp based site. Most of the site is straight up .jsp pages, but they have a few .java objects those pages use as well. I've modified one of those objects to add an extra function to it, recompiled, and yet the .jsp pages generate a "Method ... not found in class" error when I try calling it.

Obvious things I've already checked out:

- It's not a simple typo in the method name.
- The method is public.
- I'm passing the one String the method signature demands.
- The .java file has been recompiled into a .class file that has overstalled the old one.
- The object with the new function was already imported and in use.
- I have successfully modified other .java objects on this webserver (though not in this exact folder) and seen the changes take effect.

What else might it be?

Comment: What container is the server using?

Comment: I would suspect Catalina, since the company rep has mentioned Tomcat in the past. Just started looking on the server since you asked, to confirm.

Comment: Generally you have to explicitly set up hot-code replace in Tomcat, and usually it doesn't support adding method signatures - you may have to get the application redeployed and restarted to see the effects properly.

Comment: Then I'll have to hope that company's liaison is back in the office tomorrow!

Comment: added answer with some reference links for you to reference to the company liaison. You may be able to get it put into development mode for you while you work on the product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you have to explicitly set up hot-code replace in Tomcat, and usually it doesn't support adding method signatures - you may have to get the application redeployed and restarted to see the effects properly.

Here's some links for reference information about it:
[Link 1](http://old.nabble.com/How-to-hot-swap-classes--td23619847.html) 
[Link 2](http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2009/09/how_to_set_up_hot_code_replacement_with_tomcat_and_eclipse.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and links. I'll get with the other company's sysadmin first thing on business hours tomorrow to find out how he's configured this server and to reload if needed.